# log files not created in jbpm, installation incomplete

Tags: ant, jboss, jbpm

I have been trying to install jbpm6.1.0 in my Windows 7 32 bit system. However I am unable to complete so because doing an ant demo.start.noeclipse leads to a 
build.xml:508: JBoss application server did not start within 5 minutes

I have increased the time in build.xml and tried other simple tweaks. Then I was suggested to look into log files but I observed they were never created, the log folder within standalone is not present at all. I think that my installation is not getting complete and JBoss application server not starting because of that. 
I used this tutorial for installation and also used links given by it 
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.Beta2/userguide/ch.installer.html#d0e281

I am not able to debug and get to a reason. Starting the standalone.bat only gives me info that the Java_Home environment variable is set properly. I can do with a way out or even a direction as where to get more information on the process so that I may be able to debug.

Java_Home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin and ANT_HOME is C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4 with path using the C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin for its purpose. Hence both the applications must be running correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the error is because it seems that the application server is not even starting, that can be because you don't have administrator rights or because there is another server running using the required ports